# How to send/pass message to next node using node identifier in node red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am building custom node for my flow. The custom node is working properly and sending message/result to next node using `node.send(msg);` where `node=this`. It's working properly when I use this node only once. Incase if i use the same node in multiple places in same flow. it sends the message always to one(last) node. I think the script lost context of nodes. i.e., where to send the message. So, I want to replace `node.sent(msg)` to `getnode(node_id).send(msg)` so that it will always send the message to proper node. I am new to node red.So, please pardon if I failed to explain the problem. If you need more details, please let me know, i will add. Any hint would be appreciable.

Comment: Your question suggests you have not created the node properly. If you'd like some help please post to the Node-RED forum or Slack team.

Comment: @knolleary- as per your suggestion I have posted the question in detail here: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/cusom-mqtt-dynamic-certs-configurations/35729. Could you take a look. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indicates a problem with how you have created your node.

The *only* way your node should be sending messages is by calling `this.send(...)`.